# NGINX: поиск ресурса во внутренних папках

Tags: nginx

Итак, есть конфигурационный файл, вот часть конфига:

```
    location = / {
        root   www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html;

    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
        root www/resources/img;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location ~* \.(css)$ {
        root www/resources/css;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location ~* \.(js)$ {
        root www/resources/js;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
```

Если сделать запрос: `localhost/1.jpg`, то файл будет найдет во втором `location (www/resources/img)`, но если вложить в эту папку еще одну с другой картинкой, то в ней поиск происходить не будет. Как сделать, чтобы если в директории `www/resources/img` файл не нашелся, то nginx самостоятельно прошелся по внутренним папкам и там искал файл?

Comment: [try_files](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).